# pytorch sees my gpu, but tensorflow does not

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

i am not sure what is going on here. i set up a fresh gcloud instance, updated the nvidia drivers, downloaded anaconda, pytorch and tensorflow but tf can not seem to see the gpu.

my versions:

[image]

and my GPU

[image]

i tried to download tf 2.4 nightly but that did not help. I'm lost here

Comment: Please see and try tested build configurations from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu).If the issue still persists as a workaround, try to [build Tensorflow from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source). Thanks!